# How to load Javascript via wp_enqueue_script in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to add in the following Javascript into a Wordpress site.

This needs to go in before the closing `Head` tag:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="http://remote.romancart.com/js/roc_button.asp?storeid=38781"></script>
```

and this needs to go just before the closing `Body` tag:

```
<script>ROC_buttonWidget('ROC_widget','38781',113,0);</script>
```

I believe you need to add this in via a `wp_enqueue_script`. Being a newbie, I'm not sure how to write that. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Function reference for wp_enqueu_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

You can also add scripts manually, just as a less recommended alternative:

From the Wordpress dashboard, go to **Appearance > Editor** and select the **Header Template** among the template files on the right. This will bring up the code of the header template. Locate `</head>` and paste your code just before (that's the closing head tag).

The closing body tag (`</body>`) should be in the footer template (*footer.php*). Look for that template and locate the tag. Then paste your code just before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="http://remote.romancart.com/js/roc_button.asp?storeid=38781"></script> add in header.php file in your theme root folder. **if file found in your theme folder**
and
<script>ROC_buttonWidget('ROC_widget','38781',113,0);</script> and this add on footer.php file on your theme folder. **if file found in your theme folder**
```

Comment: From what I understand you should never add that into the header.php file but it should be added in via the functions.php file. I'm not sure how to write a wp_enqueue_script that would include my Javascript as above?

Comment: If you use function.php file so this script not add in head section. so that why i am tell you set script static on theme header and footer portion.

Answer (score 0):

```
function scripts_styles() {
$in_header = false;
$in_footer = true;
```

// Add javascript in header

    `wp_enqueue_script( 'script-id', 'http://remote.romancart.com/js/roc_button.asp?storeid=38781', array( 'jquery' ), '', $in_header );`

// Add javascript in footer

    `wp_enqueue_script( 'script-id', 'http://remote.romancart.com/js/roc_button.asp?storeid=38781', array( 'jquery' ), '', $in_footer );`
`}`

add this script in functions.php and use action `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_styles' );`

Comment: Thanks, this helps. When I try adding my javascript in the footer i.e. <script>ROC_buttonWidget('ROC_widget','38781',113,0);</script> I get an error when using wp_enqueue_script( 'script-id', '<script>ROC_buttonWidget('ROC_widget','38781',113,0);</script>', array( 'jquery' ), '', $in_footer ); } did i do something wrong?

Comment: function print_my_inline_script() {
  if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// js code goes here
</script>
<?php
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_my_inline_script' );

Comment: Thanks, presume that would replace // Add javascript in footer
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-id', 'http://remote.romancart.com/js/roc_button.asp?storeid=38781', array( 'jquery' ), '', $in_footer ); } ?

Comment: no this is not working you should use different way to add inline code as i show you in my first comment.